# Using a struct to pass multiple values GO

Tags: struct, go

I have just one question
I wrote an example here

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)
type PACK struct {
  d, r int
}

func main() {

  st := &PACK{}
  st.d, st.r = f(12, 32)
}

func f(a, b int) (d int, r int) {
  d = a / b
  r = a ^ b
  return
}
```

So, the question is - how can i make thing like this

```
st := &PACK{ f(1,2) }
```

I want my function return arguments to be a struct initializer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a method on struct Pack, that will initialize the values. For example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Pack struct {
    d, r int
}

func (p *Pack) init (a, b int) {
    p.d = a / b
    p.r = a ^ b
}

func main() {
    pack := Pack{}   // d and r are initialized to 0 here
    pack.init(10, 4)
    fmt.Println(pack)

}
```

Result:

```
{2 14}
```

[goplayground](http://play.golang.org/p/twzvxHbPik)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this, it is not possible.